# PopOS 22.04 - Swappiness ZRAM value, size

Tags: configuration, pop-os, zram

How to change the "zram" size in PopOS 22.04? I did not create a ram partition, I was automatically added zram, which is 16.6 gb. It has a swappiness of 180, I want to change it to swappines 10 and reduce it from 16.6 gb to 2 GB. How to do it?

PopOS 22.04

Comment: I do not know PopOS but in any case, if *You* know what you need to set is named vm.swappiness then you know its a… sysctl… so… what about *sysctl -w vm.swappiness=10* ?

Comment: And for the change being permanent, update /etc/sysctl.conf accordingly.

Comment: /etc/sysctl.conf -> vm.swappiness=10 -> Reboot -> Not working :(

Answer (score 1):

The defaults are in `/etc/default/pop-zram`.
I suggest leaving it where it is, because if you change the zram swapiness to something like 10, your system won't really benefit from zram.
What you might really want, is to have the system actively swap to zram as much as possible, since there is little to no overhead to compressing the memory (recall, the data isn't stored on a physical block device like a traditional swap, but rather the block device exists purely in memory).

Reducing it from 16 to 2 GB, will only limit the amount of your memory that can be used to store compressed memory. If you switch your swapiness to 10, and change the size to 2 GB, perhaps what you're really looking for is removing zram all together?

The 16 GB isn't 'reserved' by zram at all, it's only a virtual limit on the amount or memory that can be used to store compressed memory.  Although it gets grouped into the SWAP category, it's not slow like traditional swap.